# Can you get an external monitor running on 4k resolution at 60hz using a USB 3.0 to Displayport adapter?

Tags: usb, bandwidth, displayport, 4k-resolution

I am trying to get my new 4k monitor running at 60hz refresh rate. At the moment I have a laptop with a micro HDMI port that is most likely HDMI 1.4, since the `xrandr` outputs:

```
HDMI-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   3840x2160     30.00*   30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98    29.98  
   1920x2160     59.99  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
...
```

Are there any hopes of running at 60hz short of buying a new laptop?

I was considering this [dongle](https://www.amazon.de/I-Tec-U3DUAL4KDP-3-0-C-Adapter-schwarz/dp/B076GYJ91G/ref=sr_1_6?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1548079685&sr=1-6&keywords=usb%203.0%20displayport):

to connect from USB 3.0 to a DisplayPort. Event the seller says:

> Expand your work space by up to two external DisplayPort monitors via
>   USB 3.0, USB C or Thunderbolt 3 Port. The adaptor supports 1x 5 K
>   resolution up to 5120X2880 @ 60Hz or 2x 4 K resolution up to 4096 x
>   2160 at 60 Hz addition audio signal

However, for me, the numbers don't add up. If you would like to have a 32bit color depth with 8 megapixels times 60 frames, you get a required bandwidth of 15 Gbit/s, yet USB 3.0 has only 5 Gbit/s.

Are my calculations correct, or am I missing something? Is the pc sending out the color of each single pixel at each single frame, or just the pixels that changed? Is there perhaps some in-monitor firmware decompression? Is this just false advertising?

[image]

Comment: https://i-tec.cz/en/produkt/u3dual4kdp-2/

Comment: @Tetsujin - These are the specs that the questioner quotes, but they don't explain his arithmetic, which underestimates the quandary, since the interface claims to support **two** independent 4K displays at 60Hz with their audio channels.

Comment: @AFH - I was just linking to the manufacturer's main page on it - I wasn't trying to work out the numbers independently ;)